# SQL Query - Sum Quantity for multiple Years

Tags: sql

SQL Question - my data has products and quantity sold by fiscal period(1-12) and Fiscal year. The following SQL returns sum Quantity by period for a specific year:

```
 Select   ABS(Sum(QTY)) Total, FISCPERIOD
    From dbo.ICXLHIS
    where FISCYEAR=2016 and ITEMNUM='LBCNIQTL01100506WCP' and APP = 'PO'
    Group by FISCPERIOD
```

I want to have 2016 and 2017 data however when I add 2017 to the Where clause it returns incorrect values for the sum quantities:

```
Select   ABS(Sum(QTY)) Total, FISCPERIOD, FISCYEAR
From dbo.ICXLHIS
where FISCYEAR=2016 and FISCYEAR=2017 and ITEMNUM='LBCNIQTL01100506WCP' and 
APP = 'PO'
Group by FISCPERIOD, FISCYEAR
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Just to be sure, isn't `and` clause in `FISCYEAR=2016 and FISCYEAR=2017` a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I guess FISCALYEAR cannot be both 2016 **and** 2017. You might want to change your SQL this way:

```
Select   ABS(Sum(QTY)) Total, FISCPERIOD, FISCYEAR
From dbo.ICXLHIS
where FISCYEAR IN (2016, 2017) and 
      ITEMNUM='LBCNIQTL01100506WCP' and 
      APP = 'PO'
Group by FISCPERIOD, FISCYEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the problem `where FISCYEAR=2016 and FISCYEAR=2017`

try to do this `where FISCYEAR between (2016 and 2017)`

I hope have helped you!